# If a sniper is shooting at a target over a mile or more away, does he have to account for Earth's rotation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, reference-frames, projectile, estimation

My question is this. If a sniper is shooting at a target over a mile or more away, does he have to take into account earths rotation
Based on what I read about air and gravitational pull, I would say no.

Comment: @Alchimista Eötvös

Comment: @hyportnex. And Coriolis as for Earth and targets rotate differently it the shoot has a component along meridian

Comment: Probably have to add in the Magnus effect, as well. And the Coriolis effect is the least near the equator, so if you were shooting there, it may be ignored.

Comment: @Alchimista, I think hyportnex was correcting your spelling. :)

Comment: Coriolis and Eötvös effects. In addition to ballistic and wind.

Comment: @Bill Örtel :) Magnus effect too but is out of the Question. Let us write this as it function as an answer to OP: Yes, in addition to all consideration due to ballistic, wind, friction and bullet dynamics, a sniper do account for Earth rotation in order to correct Coriolis and Eötvös effects. Depending on shooting range and location the corrections can however be very small and even negligible.

Comment: @Alchimista, I had read somewhere (a shooting magazine?) that long-range shooters had to take into consideration the Magnus effect. I never researched it and considered the source reliable. (It's interesting that you changed the spelling of my last name to its native spelling, though I think it still has a double L.)

Comment: @Bill Oertell. Yes Magnus effect might be taken into account by snipers. But it out of scope simply because is not related to earth rotation. The question is about if earth rotation plays a role and again the answer is yes. I put the umlaut because I was just warned about misspelled Eötvös few minutes before and thought it could be funny to the readers of all comments ;)

Comment: @Alchimista, point taken.

Answer (score 1):

From *Littlewood's miscellany*, a collection of writing by the mathematician J. E. Littlewood; in the chapter "Ballistics":

> I heard an account of the [battle of the Falkland Islands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_the_Falkland_Islands) (early in the 1914 war) from an officer who was there. The German ships were destroyed at extreme range, but it took a long time and salvos were continually falling 100 yards to the left. The effect of the rotation of the earth is similar to 'drift' and was similarly incorporated in the gun-sights. But this involved the tacit assumption that Naval battles take place round about latitude 50°N. The double difference for 50°S and extreme range is of the order of 100 yards.

Comment: Aren't naval artillery shooting well over 10 miles, even in WWI?

Answer (score -2):

I agree with you.In my idea, the rotation of the earth is so much faster than the speed of bullet so the other parameters are more important than the rotation of the earth.but on the other way if you increase the target distance more and more you need to consider more and more factors like the rotation of the earth.

Comment: Physics is really more about facts — like numbers and equations.  This answer is more about feelings and opinions.  I think that's why you're being downvoted.  There are lots of numbers and physical concepts you could have looked up that are relevant to this.  For example, typical [muzzle velocities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muzzle_velocity), or the [rotation rate of the earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_rotation).  Maybe you could have googled and looked for formulas involved in the [flight of a bullet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_ballistics#Long_range_factors).